# Shell Script: Add a character in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, insert

Id like to add a character a variable.

I have a file path y/photos/family/kids.jpg.

Its currently assigned to a variable $kidsReal

Id like it to be Y:/photos/family/kids.jpg
(It needs to recognize the photos are coming from the Y drive (Y:)

So far I have (??? is where I am stuck):

```
#!/bin/bash

#find the kids.jpg back one directory and into the family directory
kids=$(find .. -type f -path *family*/* -name *kids.jpg)

#convert to absolute path
kidsReal=$(realpath ${kids})

#add : between y and / to complete path
kidsRealMod= ???
```

At the end of the day this variable just needs to be read as a file path to be inserted into a command that will also be coded into the script.

Thank you and please let me know if there are any other details needed for this simple problem.

Comment: some systems will respond correctly if your path includes a leading `/` char, so `/y/photos/...` . Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bash and a regex:

```
kidsReal='y/photos/family/kids.jpg'
[[ "$kidsReal" =~ (.)(.*) ]] && kidsRealMod="${BASH_REMATCH[1]^}:${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
echo "$kidsRealMod"
```

`^` converts first character in a variable to upper-case.

Output:

```
Y:/photos/family/kids.jpg
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Comment: Awesome! thanks, this work well for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can split your string into two parts by using `${str:from:to}` and join it again with `':'`.

```
str="Y/photos/family/img.png";
new_str=${str:0:1}:${str:1}
echo $new_str
```

Output:

```
Y:/photos/family/img.png
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach. Im still learning and appreciate the multiple ways of doing this.